# Contiously read STDIN in bash pipe

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, x11

I have the following command which I want to modify "on the fly":

```
xprop -root -spy _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP | sed 's/.*= //'
```

It outputs the current desktop and does so as well if a change happens.

I want to further modify this to which I wrote a function

```
function f () {
    while read -r line; do
        # modify stuff
        echo $final_str
    done
}
```

The problem is that as soon as I add this to the pipe I do not get any output from the script anymore.
The same things happen with piping `awk` among other things.

It seems like it works with `sed` by somehow being "lazily evaluated" I suppose?
How do I achieve this using a bash function?

Comment: Where/how are you adding it to the pipe? Do you get any output if you remove the sed portion?

Comment: You need to be more explicit about "modify stuff"

Comment: Ok this yields an interesting result.
If I pipe through sed and then my function I don't get an output, but if I only pipe my function it works.
Somehow `sed` seems to "consume" or "halt" the input

Comment: @glennjackman that doesn't really matter, for now I simply output the line without any modifications

Comment: One word: Buffering. See [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) (though this is libc behavior, not bash behavior, at fault). stdout is only flushed immediately when each line is complete by default when it goes to a TTY; if it goes to a pipe or a file it's flushed less frequently (typically, every time something like 32kb of output has built up) to reduce overhead.

Comment: BTW, `echo $final_str` is itself buggy. _Always_ quote your expansions: `echo "$final_str"` to prevent a string of `*` (for example) from being replaced with a list of filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged Linux -- as long as you're on a distro using GNU tools, `sed --unbuffered` is available to instruct `sed` to optimize for low latency rather than high throughput (as is the default).

See [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) for a detailed treatment of the problem.